# How can I get a python code to run over and over again?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a scraper that scrapes data from a website, then saves the data in .csv files. What I am looking for is a way to run this code every 10 minutes, without using a loop. I have very little knowledge on how to do this. What approach would you use?

Comment: Without using a loop? Sorry, but you have to use one if you want to repeat code, unless you want to use `cron` or something

Comment: You do not need to use loop but you can achieve this by using cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using windows or a unix based system?

If you're using UNIX, you can schedule jobs to take place at regular intervals with CRON.

Execute the following in a terminal window:

```
#edit crontab
crontab -e
```

Then add the required file you want to execute prefaced by the following CRON instructions:

```
*/6 * * * * /path/to/desired/Python_version /path/to/executable/file
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to repeat a code without a loop.

I can only think that you want something like Task Scheluding on Windows (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa383614.aspx) or crontab/timers on Linux.